# Markdown nested list: skip a level

Tags: markdown

I'm using nested bulleted lists in Markdown. In certain cases, the level must jump from depth 1 to depth 3, as below:
[image: HTML-generated nested lists]

Can this be done in pure Markdown? (Obviously it can be done in HTML, as above.) The things I try don't work:

```
* Lowest level
        - Level 3
```

(with 2x4 spaces before the level 3 bullet) becomes

- Lowest level
  - Level 3

putting it all into a single line.

```
* Lowest level  
        - Level 3
```

(with two spaces at the end of the first line) shows up as

- Lowest level
  - Level 3

where *Level 3* isn't a nested list: it is actually part of the first bullet, which has an internal `<br>` line break.

```
* Lowest level
    * 
        * Level 3
```

again puts all of it into one bullet:

- Lowest level
  *
  * Level 3

Can it be done?

Comment: But why though?

Comment: It could occur, generally speaking, when the nesting levels are ‘semantic’: they refer to something other than the nested text itself. For instance, in a list of offices of an international organization, the top level might be the country and level 3 might be the city; in large countries level 2 would be the state or province, and in small countries that wouldn’t add useful information so it would be omitted. Or in a table of contents, level 1 is chapters, 2 high-level sections, 3 lower-level sections, and there may be a chapter that starts with a lower-level section.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this look with fake level 3 items. You can build them up using non-breaking spaces and a ⦁ (Z NOTATION SPOT) character.

### Source:

```
- Lowest level[space][space]
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;⦁ &nbsp;&nbsp;Level 3: **this skipped level 2**[space][space]
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;⦁ &nbsp;&nbsp;3 again
    - Level 2
- Back at level 1
```

### Result:

- Lowest level
            ⦁   Level 3: **this skipped level 2**
            ⦁   3 again

  - Level 2
- Back at level 1

##### For comparison, here's a real list with 3 levels:

- Level 1

  - Level 2

    - Level 3